# log4net log file is created but always empty

Tags: log4net

I have a web site project where I'd like to log via log4net. When I try it, **log file is created but it is always empty**.

Here is part of the Global.asax file:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Log4Net.config")));
    var log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    log.Info("Logging started");       
}
```

And here is Log4Net.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>  
  <root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
  </root>

  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  </appender>
  <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="admin_log.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a problem in your configuration, enable internal debug to see what it is:

```
<configuration>
...
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>

...

    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true">
            <listeners>
                <add 
                    name="textWriterTraceListener" 
                    type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                    initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

[Log4net FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html)

Comment: Layout element was missing in my FileAppender. I was hoping that there is some default layout.